# Using Pivot_Table with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas with Python 3.7. I have a csv file with 8 columns, and I need to pivot columns 5, 6, 7, and 8. I pivot them like so:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table (csv_file, 
                        values = ["column 5", "column 6" , "column 7","column 8"],
                        index = "ID",
                        aggfunc = np.mean,
                        dropna = False)
```

I then save it to a csv. The problem is that the saved csv file only has columns 5, 6, 7, and 8. I want it to keep the first 4 columns as well. I have tried to find workarounds, such as dropping the last 4 columns from csv_file, then adding the columns back after they are pivoted. I have tried concatenating, joining, and merging, with no success in recreating a csv file with all 8 columns after pivoting. If anyone has any insight or knowledge on how to perform this task I would greatly appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

I dont have your csv_file as input but I tried to do something like this. See if this is what you are looking for.

```
c1 = [i for i in range(10)]
c2 = [i for i in range(10)]
c3 = [str(i) for i in range (10)]
c4 = [str(i) for i in range (10,0,-1)]
c5 = ['test']*10

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':c1,'column2':c2,
                   'column3':c3,'column4':c4,'column5':c5,})

df_pivot=pd.pivot_table(df,
                  values=['column1', 'column2'], 
                  index=["column3","column4","column5"], 
                  aggfunc={'column1':[np.mean,max,min],'column2':np.sum})

#df_pivot.columns = df_pivot.columns.get_level_values(1)

df_pivot.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df_pivot.columns.values]

print(df)
print(df_pivot)
```

The outputs will be as follows:

**Initial dataframe:**

```
   column1  column2 column3 column4 column5
0        0        0       0      10    test
1        1        1       1       9    test
2        2        2       2       8    test
3        3        3       3       7    test
4        4        4       4       6    test
5        5        5       5       5    test
6        6        6       6       4    test
7        7        7       7       3    test
8        8        8       8       2    test
9        9        9       9       1    test
```

**Pivot Dataframe**

```
                         column1_max  column1_mean  column1_min  column2_sum
column3 column4 column5                                                     
0       10      test               0             0            0            0
1       9       test               1             1            1            1
2       8       test               2             2            2            2
3       7       test               3             3            3            3
4       6       test               4             4            4            4
5       5       test               5             5            5            5
6       4       test               6             6            6            6
7       3       test               7             7            7            7
8       2       test               8             8            8            8
9       1       test               9             9            9            9
```

I got a few minutes to work on your problem statement. You need to call out which columns to write to your file. Here's what I did.

**Writing to a CSV file**

```
df_pivot.to_csv('out.csv', index_label=df_pivot.columns.name)
```

The output of this will be as follows. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
column3,column4,column5,column1_max,column1_mean,column1_min,column2_sum
0,10,test,0,0,0,0
1,9,test,1,1,1,1
2,8,test,2,2,2,2
3,7,test,3,3,3,3
4,6,test,4,4,4,4
5,5,test,5,5,5,5
6,4,test,6,6,6,6
7,3,test,7,7,7,7
8,2,test,8,8,8,8
9,1,test,9,9,9,9
```

**Writing to an Excel file**

```
import openpyxl

with pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx',engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    df_pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',columns=df_pivot.columns)
```

The answer I got is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Looks like this helped you get the issue addressed. If this did, please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me.  I changed my code to mimic your suggestion.I do not know why you are joining on underscore, but with or without that line, the saved csv file still only includes the last 4 columns.

Comment: Let me write code to push the data into a csv file as well and give it to you.

Comment: see if this helps you. https://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-report.html

Comment: That results in the same problem that I am dealing with. It appears that the only difference is that the index is passed in before the values.

Comment: No worries. I have a few mins of free time. Let me solve that for you.

Comment: @JoeCarter, see if this addresses your problem. If not. lets work on solving it.